# redirect to parent record visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am using the below method in button tag in visualforce page. After insert i want to redirect to the parent record detail page. currently it is not happening. Please help.

```
public class BIAcontroller
{
    public BIAcontroller(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        account=new BIA__c();
        // other constructor operations
    }

    public BIA__c account{ get; set; }
    // other properties

    public PageReference processSelected() 
    {
        //do stuff
        insert account;

        PageReference nextPage = new PageReference('/' + account.id);
        // nextPage.setRedirect(true);
        return nextPage;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are currently redirecting to a list view (`PageReference('/a0U/o');`). If this is the right moment/condition you want to redirect, replace it with `PageReference('/'+account.id);`. Also you should clarify what you mean by parent object.

Comment: BIA__c account = new BIA__c is the parent one and Team__c is the related list to BIA__c.After the operation is finished it should redirect to newly created BIA__c record.

Comment: Hi.. I have updated my controller. After modifying that part , the page is not redirecting to the record. Please help.

Comment: Looks like you are not inserting `bia__c`, perhaps before returning it, insert it first, then redirect to it's id.

Comment: insert account; this line is inserting BIA__c record then updating Team__c record then i am redirecting.Please help me in understanding..

Comment: @Sid Please try to remove parts of your code that have nothing to do with the question. I have taken that liberty here because your question was very cluttered as originally posted.

Answer (score 2):

Generally if I have an `SObject` and I want to redirect to it via `PageReference`, I will use the following:

```
SObject record; // can be of any type
PageReference view = new ApexPages.standardController(record).view();
```